# Why does my retina-display-specific image show up bigger than the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am developing a wallpaper app, made solely for retina display iPhones. I have a 640 x 960 pixels sized image, `legends.jpg`, that I want to display in a view, as a preview. Here's my code in `loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView
{

    // Init the main view first.
    UIView *wallpaperContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIImage *wallpaper = [UIImage imageNamed:@"legends.jpg"];

    UIImageView *wallpaperView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:wallpaper];

    [wallpaperContainerView addSubview:wallpaperView];

    [self setView:wallpaperContainerView]; 
}
```

My questions are:

1. When I run it on the Simulator (iPhone Retina 3.5 inch), the image looks bigger than the entire screen, only showing the top left portion of it. Why is this the case, when the 3.5inch iPhones resolution is 640x960, similar with my image's size? What should I add to my code to make the image fit the screen?
2. If I'm **only** targeting retina display iPhones, should I append all my image file names with "@2x" and leave out the non "@2x" files?

### Update

Thanks to the suggestions below, I created the legends.png (for non-retina) and legends@2x.png files. Then, I modified the `*wallpaper` initialization to:

```
UIImage *wallpaper = [UIImage imageNamed:@"legends"];
```

This **completely** solves my #1 question. So apparently using JPG causes this scaling confusion, while with PNG everything works fine.

Comment: Remember that the iPad mini can run iPhone apps, and does not have a retina screen. You should always have non-retina versions.

Comment: Yes for retina iPhone you need to keep @2x extension. But as advices - it's better to keep normal images as well since on Appstore you won't be able to block people from downloading your application on those basis (only iPhone, iPad filters are possible)

Answer (score 1):

iPhone Retina screen is 3.5 inch but its resolution is double than non retina screens. So you have to include image resources for supporting both retina and non retina displays. Retina resource image name should have a suffix @2x. So include images with 320x480 (non retina) and 640x960 (retina) resolutions, your problem will get over.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use @2x in the filename of the Retina version of your image.

And by the way, try to always use PNG format, as you won't have to bother in the future with filename extensions.

For instance, if you've got 2 files (normal and Retina with suffix @2x.png) you could simply write:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"legends"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to manage **Iphone 5 screens** that have a height of 568.

Here is something that can be handy :

```
#define IS_PHONEPOD5() ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0f && 
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f &&
 UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        if(IS_PHONEPOD5())
        {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-568h@2x"];
        }
        else
        {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
        }
}
```